# I am a certain type of questin about Data Stream, I just need to count it but I have absolutely no clue how

Tags: dataframe

What will be the bitrate of 320x200 video at 25 fps, which is compressed by a videocodec with a compression ratio of 1: 150? Write with a formula.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thats all, just need to know how to count it.